# Symfony 1 - set JSON content type automatically for every AJAX request

Tags: symfony1

In my webapplication, I always reply with JSON to AJAX calls.
Thus I find myself doing this on a lot of actions:

```
if ($request->isXmlHttpRequest()) {
    $this->getResponse()->setHttpHeader('Content-type', 'application/json');
    return $this->renderText(json_encode($details));
}
```

Is there a way to get that automatically: anytime the request is AJAX, the content type is JSON?

I was thinking I should use a filter maybe but I am not familiar with filters and maybe there is a better solution.

Any suggestion will be more than welcome.

Thanks,
Dan

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way I solved it:

Create a new class `myActions` which extends from `sfActions`. In this class create a new function `renderJson($data)`:

```
protected function renderJson($data) {
  $this->getResponse()->setHttpHeader('Content-type', 'application/json');
  return $this->renderText(json_encode($data));
}
```

Now let your controller class inherit from `myActions` (instead of `sfActions`). And at the end of your controller just `return $this->renderJson($data);`.

(I also did some templating. in the renderJson, if the `sf_debug` is set in the config, and it's not requested through XmlHttp.)

Answer (score 0):

I'm using a similar technique in one of my projects, but I'd suggest also taking a look at [this article](http://symfony.com/blog/how-to-create-an-optimized-version-of-your-website-for-the-iphone-in-symfony-1-1) regarding iPhone optimization.  You can set your routing to accept a format and return the appropriate template based on that.  Then you don't need to set the header as it's set by the requested format.

Of course, this means you'll need to create separate template files for each output template, which seems a bother, or use a particular layout file and skip the template.  So in the end it may amount to pretty much the same thing (or same amount of code, at least).